# How to get balance of an address using Cardanosharp

Tags: c#

I am trying to develop a simple program where I am able to generate an address successfully using a public key and a stake key. The network type is `TestNet`.

How can I check the balance of the generated address?

Code snippet is as follow:

```
var existingaddresses = _Addresses.Find(x => x.WalletId == wallet.Id).ToList().Count;
            var user = _users.Find(x => x.Id == wallet.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
            NetworkType net;
            if (IsMainNet)
            {
                net = NetworkType.Mainnet;
            }
            else
            {
                net = NetworkType.Testnet;
            }
            Mnemonic mnc = keyService.Restore(wallet.Words, WordLists.English);
            PrivateKey masterKey = mnc.GetRootKey(user.Password);
            string PaymentPath = $"m/1852'/1815'/0'/0/"+ existingaddresses;
            PrivateKey paymentPrv = masterKey.Derive(PaymentPath);
            PublicKey paymentPub = paymentPrv.GetPublicKey(false);
            string stakePath = $"m/1852'/1815'/0'/2/"+existingaddresses;
            PrivateKey stakePrv = masterKey.Derive(stakePath);
            PublicKey stakePub = stakePrv.GetPublicKey(false);

            Address address = addressService.GetAddress(paymentPub, stakePub, net, AddressType.Base);
```

Now I want to check the balance of the generated address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Blockfrost.io](https://blockfrost.io/) API to get information about the address. I'd recommend using the [blockfrost-dotnet](https://github.com/blockfrost/blockfrost-dotnet) package for this.

Comment: I have tried it but i am getting content not found exception which means this Address doesnot exist on test net. Isnt it? What can be the reason?

Comment: I think this happens if the address has never been used.

Comment: agreed. as address is never used. Any idea what can be done to activate the address on testnet?

Comment: Send some tADA to that address: https://testnets.cardano.org/en/testnets/cardano/tools/faucet/